# how UPDATE rows in cassandra using only Partition Key?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cql, cql3

My table looks like this

```
create table Notes(
    user_id varchar,
    real_time timestamp,
    insertion_time timeuuid,
    read boolean PRIMARY KEY (user_id,real_time,insertion_time)
);

create index read_index on Notes (read);
```

I want **update all** the **rows** with **user_id** = 'xxx' **without** having to specify all the clustering indexes.

```
UPDATE Notes SET read = true where user_id = 'xxx'; // Says Error
```

Error: message="Missing mandatory PRIMARY KEY part real_time

I have tried creating a secondary index, but its not allowed on the primary key.

How can i solve this?

I chose user_id to be in the primary key cause i want to be able to do `select * from Notes where user_id = 'xxx'` should be possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While this might be possible with a RDBMS and SQL, it is not possible with cql in Cassandra.  From the DataStax documentation on the [UPDATE](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/update_r.html) command:

> Each update statement requires a precise set of primary keys to be specified using a WHERE clause. You need to specify all keys in a table having compound and clustering columns.

You'll probably need to write something quick in Python (or one of the other drivers) to perform this type of update.

Comment: Though the above answer is correct I think it's worth mentioning that you can use the `IN` clause for the last column of the primary key (i.e. `insertion_time` from the authors question). Depending on your use case this is useful to reduce the required amount of CQL statements.